# Add module to Magento Marketplace - where can I find their official tester utility

Tags: magento2, module, marketplace

I intend to add my first module to Magento marketplace.

While reading the documents they say that in the first step the module will go into a first automatic test phase using their utility and they encourage people to download this script and test before application. But the link provided is not working.

Anyone know how can I get it ?

Thanks !!!